# Associating the Maximum of Subgroups in One Column with Another Column in R

Tags: r, max

I'm an elementary-level user of R, and I'm looking at a task that has me somewhat stumped.  I have a dataset with one column that lists the title of several thousands of (local) newspapers and another two columns that list circulation of the newspaper in counties near the headquarters of the newspaper (using a unique county ID for each county instead of the potentially non-unique county name).

Thus, sometimes a single newspaper occupies five rows or less, sometimes ten rows or more, depending on the volume of circulation in surrounding counties.  What I need to do is associate the county ID of the county in which circulation of a given paper is highest with all rows corresponding to that paper.  That is, to give an example for three newspapers that circulate in a similar area,

```
Paper        CountyID    Circulation  MaxCountyID
Times           1           1000          2
Times           2           2000          2
Times           3            500          2
Chronicle       1           5000          1
Chronicle       2           4000          1
Chronicle       3           1000          1
Tribune         1            900          1
Tribune         3            700          1
```

Although the circulation numbers are naturally far less round than this in the actual dataset, given its sheer size, I anticipate that I will run into ties for highest circulation in at least a couple of cases, so I think I will need to somehow deal with that eventuality as well; it is fine for any of the tied counties to appear as the MaxCounty.

EDIT: The second--and final--part of what I need to do is to (from what I have now) generate a three-column dataset that specifies, in each row, the total circulation in county y of papers from county x, where "papers from county x" is defined to mean "all papers for which county x is the max.county".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care which one of the ties appears, then use `which.max` which will select the first one:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(paper = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"), county = c(1:3), circulation = c(10,20,20,10,20,30))

dt[, max.county := county[which.max(circulation)], by = paper]
dt
#   paper county circulation max.county
#1:     A      1          10          2
#2:     A      2          20          2
#3:     A      3          20          2
#4:     B      1          10          3
#5:     B      2          20          3
#6:     B      3          30          3
```

You could also keep all of them in a list, or select randomly:

```
dt[, max.county := NULL]
dt[, max.county := list(list(county[circulation == max(circulation)])), by = paper]

dt[, max.county := NULL]
dt[, max.county := sample(as.list(county[circulation == max(circulation)]), 1), by = paper])
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I'm getting an error message: "unused argument(s) (by = paper)"

Comment: You probably forgot to convert your data to `data.table`, i.e. `dt = data.table(your_data_frame)`

Comment: Indeed you are correct.  Thanks for bearing with me!  The second--and final--part of what I need to do is to (from what I have now) generate a three-column dataset that specifies, in each row, the total circulation in county y of papers from county x, where "papers from county x" is defined to mean "all papers for which county x is the max.county".  Any potential suggestions?  By the way, I'm new to stackoverflow, so I'm not entirely sure of the favored method for asking follow-ups; perhaps I should edit this in to the initial question as well.

Comment: @BrianWheaton - I'm afraid I don't follow, you should probably post an example of start and end data and explain how you get there

Answer (score 0):

Going off of eddi's answer, but taking a new approach

there is a simple 3 step approach to this problem:

1, create a variable A that stores the maximum circulation value for each paper

```
 a<- aggregate(dt$circulation, by=list(paper=dt$paper), FUN= max)
```

2, Find the county in your database that corresponds to this max value for each paper. This will only create one row per max value,
even if you have a tie. Trim b to two columns.

```
    b<- dt[dt$paper== a$paper  & dt$circulation == a$x, ]   
    b<- b[,2:3]
```

3.Merge the two tables (left outer join)

```
merge(x=dt, y=b, by= "paper", all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I get an error message when trying the first part of step 2.  "Warning messages:
1: In dt$paper == a$paper :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In dt$circulation == a$x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the dplyr package.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% group_by(COUNTY_ID) %>% mutate(MaxCountyID = max(Circulation))
```

The above line will add the column MaxCountyID to dt. If you wanted to filter to see all newspapers where a county is max you can expand the above to the following.

```
dt %>% group_by(County_ID) %>% mutate(MaxCountyID = max(Circulation)) %>% filter(MaxCountyID == 2)
```

In the above, 2 represents the countyID you want to filter to.